# Override Font Awesome icon whit background image

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to override/replace Font Awesome icon with background image. I have only CSS access.

What I have: [image: plus button]

```
.btn.btn-default.bootstrap-touchspin-up:before {
    font-family: Fontawesome;
    content: "\f067";
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:[image: plus-2]

```
.btn.btn-default.bootstrap-touchspin-up:before {
    background-image : url(Images/arrows-left-right.png);
    font-family: initial;
    content: "";
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why not make it an inline-block, put a 1px border on it and increase the border radius till it's round?

Comment: I tried that already, but still can't change font-weight to make it slim like that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need these additional properties

```
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block; 
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
```

as mentioned by  @Alexander De Sousa in comments, inline-block is much better choice to keep everything inline.

Comment: Maybe worth noting for future people who find this, display: block will take up the whole width so it won't behave like a "character", this may solve OP's specific problem but could confuse future people without this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML:

```
    <span class="btn btn-default"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.btn:before {
  font-family: Fontawesome;
  content: "\f067";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/5181/

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
display:inline-block;
```

That's all you need. As standard :before and :after are inline, so they'll collapse in regardless of height and width. Inline-block will get you what you want.